# Rustの"unwrap()"は何をするものですか？

Tags: rust

Rust言語を最近はじめました。
stdライブラリから少しずつコードを読んでいますが、
一つわからないことがあります。

頻繁に出てくる`unwrap()`函数が、
何のために、何に対して、何を返してるのか、が把握できません。

英語のドキュメントをみても、いまいち意味が飲み込めず、、。
ご存知の方がいましたら、ご教授ください。

Comment: 英語版にも同じような質問がありましたので、参考までにコメントで追記しておきます: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257686/what-is-this-unwrap-thing-sometimes-its-unwrap-sometimes-unwrap-or

Comment: タイトルだけで問題を把握してもらいやすいように、さらには回答をもらいやすいように編集してみました。気にいらないところなどあれば (お手数ですが) [edit]して上書きしてしまってください。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`unwrap()` は、 `Option<T>` 型や `Result<T, E>` 型の値（つまり、何かしらの値を *ラップ* している値）から中身の値を取り出す関数です。たとえば `Option<T>` 型の値に対して `unwrap()` を呼ぶと、それが内包する `T` 型の値を返します。

`unwrap()` は失敗するかもしれないことに注意が必要です。 `Option<T>` 型や `Result<T, E>` 型などの値は、 `T` 型の値が入っていることもあれば入っていないこともあります。入っていない場合に `unwrap()` を呼ぶとプログラムは panic します。

```
let opt: Option<i32> = Some(42);
println!("{}", opt.unwrap()); // 42 を表示
let opt: Option<i32> = None;
println!("{}", opt.unwrap()); // ここで panic
```

`unwrap()` は記述を簡潔にするためサンプルコードで使用されることがありますが、普段は使用を避けてパターンマッチや `unwrap_or()` などの安全な関数で値を取り出したほうがいいでしょう。

```
let opt: Option<i32> = None;
match opt {
    Some(_) => println!("some!"),
    None => println!("none!"),
}
// none! を表示

println!("{}", opt.unwrap_or(0)); // 0 を表示
```

動作は `unwrap()` と同じですが panic したときのカスタムメッセージを指定できる `expect()` もあります。値が入っていることが確実に分かっていて、そうでなければバグとしてクラッシュしていいという場合には `expect()` を使ってもよいでしょう。

`RefCell<T>` なども何かしらの値をラップしている値といえますが、この場合は `T` 型の値が入っていることが保証されています。必ず中身が入っている型から内包された値を取り出す関数は、panic しないことを明確にするため `unwrap()` ではなく `into_inner()` と命名されています。

Comment: わかりやすい解説ありがとうございます。